# Markdown install error

Tags: python, django, markdown

l have a problem with `Markdown` install and l m using `Python3.5` version. By using `pip install markdown` and l got this error below:

Command ""c:\users\ömer sarı\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Windows\Temp\pip-build-zyp_5g0x\markdown\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Windows\Temp\pip-ckif2kvg-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Windows\Temp\pip-build-zyp_5g0x\markdown\

before that, l tried to install `Django-markdown` but it failed due to same problem above. How can l solve this issue?

Comment: sorry, but this is not enough info. is there a more specific error message? are you using some sort of virtual enviroment? at my local unix system the markdown install worked flawlessly...

Comment: l installed virtual environment. l have win 10 operating system. l shared all necessary info but after installing virtual environment, probably ,virtual environment in python35 must be created.

Comment: l did  not create any virtual environment for this project